# I got the error when I am trying to delete items of Recycler View

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I am  using Recycler  View for displaying the items from shared preference ID.I have to delete the Recyler View items as well as SharedPreference store items.
But I got error when I trying to delete the items of Recycler View.

My Adapter:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.journaldev.navigationdrawer.ActionBarIconProcess.Cart;
import com.journaldev.navigationdrawer.ActionBarIconProcess.CartItems;
import com.journaldev.navigationdrawer.ActionBarIconProcess.Wishlist;
import com.journaldev.navigationdrawer.Activity.singleshooppingcart;
import com.journaldev.navigationdrawer.Constants.Constants;
import com.journaldev.navigationdrawer.Model.CartItemoriginal;
import com.journaldev.navigationdrawer.Model.CartitemModel;
import com.journaldev.navigationdrawer.Model.Cartitemoringinaltwo;
import com.journaldev.navigationdrawer.R;
import com.journaldev.navigationdrawer.app.YelloPage;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by admin on 6/2/2016.
 */
public class CartlistAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter < CartlistAdapter.ViewHolder > {

        private ArrayList < CartItemoriginal > cartlistadp;
        private ArrayList < Cartitemoringinaltwo > cartlistadp2;
        DisplayImageOptions options;
        private Context context;
        public static final String MYCARTPREFERENCE = "CartPrefs";
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        SharedPreferences shared;
        String pos;
        String date;
        String currentDateandTime;
        private static final int VIEW_TYPE_ONE = 1;
        private static final int VIEW_TYPE_TWO = 2;
        private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
        private Double orderTotal = 0.00;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0");
        Double extPrice;



        public CartlistAdapter(ArrayList < CartItemoriginal > cartlistadp, ArrayList < Cartitemoringinaltwo > cartlistadp2, Context context) {

            this.cartlistadp = cartlistadp;
            this.cartlistadp2 = cartlistadp2;
            this.context = context;
            options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheOnDisk(true).cacheInMemory(true).showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.b2)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.b2).build();
            if (YelloPage.imageLoader.isInited()) {
                YelloPage.imageLoader.destroy();
            }
            YelloPage.imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
        }
        public CartlistAdapter() {

        }


        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            if (cartlistadp.size() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(cartlistadp), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return VIEW_TYPE_TWO;
            }
            return VIEW_TYPE_ONE;
        }


        @Override
        public CartlistAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {

            ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
            switch (position) {
                case VIEW_TYPE_TWO:
                    View view2 = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_cart, viewGroup, false);
                    viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view2);
                    // return view holder for your placeholder
                    break;
                case VIEW_TYPE_ONE:
                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cartitemrow, viewGroup, false);
                    viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
                    // return view holder for your normal list item
                    break;
            }
            return viewHolder;

        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(CartlistAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
            viewHolder.productnames.setText(cartlistadp.get(position).getProductname());
            viewHolder.cartalisname.setText(cartlistadp.get(position).getAliasname());
            viewHolder.cartprice.setText("Rs" + " " + cartlistadp.get(position).getPrice());
            viewHolder.cartdelivery.setText(cartlistadp2.get(position).getDelivery());
            viewHolder.cartshippin.setText(cartlistadp2.get(position).getShippincharge());
            viewHolder.cartsellername.setText(cartlistadp2.get(position).getSellername());
            viewHolder.Error.setText(cartlistadp2.get(position).getError());
            viewHolder.qty.setTag(cartlistadp.get(position));
            if (cartlistadp.get(position).getQty() != 0) {
                viewHolder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(cartlistadp.get(position).getQty()));
            } else {
                viewHolder.qty.setText("0");
            }
            //  viewHolder.qty.setText(cartlistadp.get(position).getQty());
            // viewHolder.wishrating.setText(WishListadp.get(i).getCartitemname());
            YelloPage.imageLoader.displayImage(cartlistadp.get(position).getProductimg(), viewHolder.cartitemimg, options);

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            int it = 0;
            if (cartlistadp.equals(cartlistadp)) {
                it = cartlistadp.size();
            }
            if (cartlistadp2.equals(cartlistadp2)) {
                it = cartlistadp2.size();
            }
            return it;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return cartlistadp2.get(position);
        }


        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            private TextView productnames, cartalisname, cartprice, cartdelivery, cartshippin, cartsellername, Error, total;
            private ImageView cartitemimg;
            private ImageButton wishbtn, removebtn;
            private LinearLayout removecart, movewishlist;
            private CardView cd;
            private EditText qty;

            public ViewHolder(final View view) {
                    super(view);
                    productnames = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cartitemname);
                    cartalisname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cartalias);
                    cartprice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.CartAmt);
                    cartdelivery = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cartdel);
                    cartshippin = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.shippingcrg);
                    cartsellername = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cartSellerName);
                    cartitemimg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cartimg);
                    Error = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.error);

                    removecart = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.removecart);
                    movewishlist = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.movewishlist);
                    Error = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.error);

                    qty = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
                    qty.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(view));

                    qty.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                            qty.setSelection(qty.getText().length());
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    shared = view.getContext().getSharedPreferences(MYCARTPREFERENCE, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    editor = view.getContext().getSharedPreferences(MYCARTPREFERENCE, context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();


                    cd = (CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cv);
                    productnames.setSingleLine(false);
                    productnames.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
                    productnames.setMaxLines(2);

                    totalPrice();

                    //  view.setClickable(true);
                    //  view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

                    removecart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if (cartlistadp.size() == 1) {
                                Intent list = new Intent(v.getContext(), Cart.class);
                                context.startActivity(list);
                                ((Activity) context).finish();
                                removeAt(getPosition());
                                Log.i(String.valueOf(getPosition()), "item");
                                Toast.makeText(context, "All items deleted from your WishList", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else {
                                removeAt(getPosition());


                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Error:

```
: 30: 03.108 2118 - 2118 / com.journaldev.navigationdrawer E / AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.journaldev.navigationdrawer, PID: 2118
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected.Invalid item position 1(offset: -1).state: 2
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java: 4320)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java: 4278)
at com.journaldev.navigationdrawer.Adapter.CustomLinearLayoutManagercartpage.measureScrapChild(CustomLinearLayoutManagercartpage.java: 67)
at com.journaldev.navigationdrawer.Adapter.CustomLinearLayoutManagercartpage.onMeasure(CustomLinearLayoutManagercartpage.java: 38)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java: 2343)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java: 17547)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java: 5535)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java: 1436)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java: 722)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java: 613)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java: 17547)
at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(NestedScrollView.java: 1415)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java: 436)
at android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView.onMeasure(NestedScrollView.java: 480)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java: 17547)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java: 5535)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java: 1436)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java: 722)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java: 613)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java: 17547)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java: 727)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java: 463)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java: 17547)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java: 5535)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java: 436)
at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java: 124)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java: 17547)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java: 5535)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java: 1436)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java: 722)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java: 613)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java: 17547)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java: 5535)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java: 436)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java: 17547)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java: 5535)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java: 1436)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java: 722)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java: 613)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java: 17547)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java: 5535)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java: 436)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java: 2615)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java: 17547)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java: 2015)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java: 1173)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java: 1379)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java: 1061)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java: 5885)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java: 767)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java: 580)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java: 550)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java: 753)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java: 739)
at android.os.Handler.dispa
06 - 09 08: 30: 53.097 2118 - 2118 / com.journaldev.navigationdrawer I / Process: Sending signal.PID: 2118 SIG:
```

How to solve this problem I am using two model for one adapter might be because of I am getting error like this .
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you request for an index that is either negative, or greater than or equal to the size of your arraylist, an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown

Answer (score 1):

try `getAdapterPosition()` instead of `getPosition` .when calling `removeAt`

Answer (score 0):

On your getItem(int position) you are returning your cartlistadp2(arraylist2) that is the problem.

I don't know what the below code actually does in getItemCount() but use this code for getItem() also

```
  if (cartlistadp.equals(cartlistadp)) {
               return cartlistadp.get(position);
            }
            if (cartlistadp2.equals(cartlistadp2)) {
              return cartlistadp2.get(position);
            }
```

Comment: This is not the right way to compare the arraylist.

In your comparsion you will get carlistadp size as count of your list and cartlistadp2 as item for your list. so that's why you are getting arrayindexoutofboundexception i.e removeAt(getposition()) will cause arrayindexoutofboundexception

Comment: How to get the position from the item model